# Real estate investment and growth data sources

Tags: real-estate, global, economy

I am searching for public sources of real estate / property investment activity / levels from which to find trending data for countries. I've looked through the World Bank data catalogue and found nothing on housing, I've looked through IMF and don't see anything that focuses on property markets. Are there sources for this kind of data available?